# I need opinion on how to terminate an operation (parsing an empty string to double)

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, null, numberformatexception

I'm writing an ATM code, but I'm facing a simple problem ( I hope ) which is when I click on the deposit button, a new window pops up with buttons on it (0 to 9), which the user inputs the amount he wishes, then by pressing submit, the text in the label is parsed to double then returned to the deposit method which increases the balance (double) by the amount returned. The problem is when the user opens the deposit pop up and then closes it by clicking the X button, the string returns a null character which gives me an error (NumberFormatException: empty string) because you can't parse null to double.

I tried an if statement for if the string is null, let it be "0", but then the transactions history (an array of Strings) stores "Deposit: 0$", which isn't true because he didn't click the submit button (also it's illogical). So I need to know how if the string is null to maybe like terminate the operation and return to the previous scene without returning any value to the deposit method.

Here's the returning code

```
String value = labelNum.getText();
if(value == null || value.isEmpty()) { value = ""; }
return Double.valueOf(value);
```

and this is the method it's returned to:

```
  public void setDeposit(double deposit) { balance = balance + deposit; }
```

Comment: How about returning null or 0 in the case of an empty string? Like `if(value == null || value.isEmpty()) return null or 0`?

Comment: What method surrounds your first code snippet? `setDeposit` isn't calling any methods so the first code snippet can't return to it...

Comment: Don't use Double for money amounts.

Comment: It's called in the event handling of the button "Deposit", the return is stored in a variable (double) and then this variable is sent to the deposit function which is in my question

Comment: I fail to see the "whole picture" here: What is wrong with checking the input before actually making the deposit: `submit.setOnAction(evt -> { String value = labelNum.getText(); if (value != null) { try { makeDeposit(Double.parseDouble(value)); } catch (NumberFormatException ex) { ...handle erroneous input... }}});` BTW you'll mislead most developers by using `setDeposit` as method name the method name suggests that it sets a property and calling the method twice with the same parameter wouldn't result in a update of the object. I recommend changing the name to something like `makeDeposit`...

Answer (score 0):

going with @FailingCoder, you could add some defensive coding to the `if` statement and within the `setDeposit()` function as well so as to make the code check for `deposit = 0` statements. For example,

```
if(value != null && !value.isEmpty()){
    return Double.valueOf(value);
}
else
    return 0.0;
```

and in the `setDeposit()` function

```
public void setDeposit(double deposit) 
{ 
    if(deposit > 0) //to avoid negative entries else != should also work
    balance = balance + deposit; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend something along the lines of this assuming that you have the proper regex filtering out letters subtractions symbols but the way you worded it makes it sound like that shouldn't be a problem because theres only numbers 1-9 I coded it out so you get an idea of what is going on then your not trying to return null or 0.0 depending on how you have it coded you could bind your account balance and the label for it then you don't have to "refresh" the label which I hate but this is just so you can get an idea of other ways around this problem

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private Label balanceLabel;
    private double accountBalance = 0.0;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        balanceLabel = new Label();
        setNewAccountBalanceLabel();

        Button depositButton = new Button("Deposit Money");
        depositButton.setOnAction(event -> depositAction());

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(balanceLabel, depositButton);

        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        stage.show();
    }

    private void setNewAccountBalanceLabel(){ 
        balanceLabel.setText("Balance:"+accountBalance);
    }

    private void depositAction(){
        getDepositAmount();
        setNewAccountBalanceLabel();
    }

    private void getDepositAmount(){
        Stage stage  = new Stage();

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Label depositAmountLabel = new Label("0.00");

        TextField depositAmountTextField = new TextField();
        depositAmountTextField.setPromptText("Only Numbers");
        depositAmountTextField.setOnKeyReleased(keyEvent-> depositAmountLabel.setText(depositAmountTextField.getText()));

        Button submitButton = new Button("Submit");
        submitButton.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            double depositAmount = Double.parseDouble(depositAmountLabel.getText());
            accountBalance = accountBalance + depositAmount;
            stage.close();
        });

        vBox.getChildren().addAll(depositAmountLabel, depositAmountTextField, submitButton);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(vBox));
        stage.showAndWait();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```